# Is there a way to get Custom DateTime Pattern With TimeZone Offset as Request Param in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create an API that would take the startTime and endTime `OffsetDateTime` as Request Param with custom DateTimePattern along with TimeZone Offset value as well.
I want the DateTime pattern to take value up to minutes only. Like this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` but I don't know how to add offset information in this pattern.
Below is the Controller class

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getUsers(
        @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") OffsetDateTime startTime,
        @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") OffsetDateTime endTime)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?
The purpose of this API is to get the Data based on startTime and endTime and also handle the TimeZone as well.

Comment: Look at the docs, search for the word 'offset' https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Thanks @Michael but the predefined formatters include seconds as well.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use the predefined formatters. Scroll down! There is an explanation of the pattern characters.

Comment: Ah, I see, there are characters to represent zone Offset. So it should be able to get the desired pattern and convert that to OffsetDateTime or will I have to get the startTime and endTime as String and then apply the pattern?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the offset in an `OffsetDateTime` object. Do you understand that a date with time but no offset or time zone is inherently ambiguous?

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this is by getting the startTime and endTime by request parameter which gives it in string, format that and then cast them in your OffSetDateTime.

Comment: I noticed if the start and end time is to be passed as String it would commit the '+' sign. i-e 2022-10-10 16:28+05:00 would be treated as 2022-10-10T16:28 05:00

Comment: format it in your desired format

Comment: and you can easily search on google how to cast to OffSetDateTime

Comment: dit it worked this time

Answer (score 0):

```
// OffsetDateTime
DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mm a xx");
print("OffsetDateTime", formatter1.format(OffsetDateTime.now()));
        
// OffsetTime
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a xx");
print("OffsetTime", formatter2.format(OffsetTime.now()));

static void print(String type, String result) {
    System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", type, result);
}
```

Your output will look like

```
OffsetDateTime: 10/12/2022 at 10:40 AM +0530
OffsetTime: 10:40 AM +0530
```

Hope it helps